# If I create OOP JS code using prototype, how do I reference a class method from a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'll show you my code first:

```
function Messages(){
    this.postResponseButton = '#postResponseButton';
    $(document).ready(this.setEvents);
}
Messages.prototype.setEvents = function(){
    $(self.postResponseButton).click(function(){
        this.postResponse(); // ERROR HERE
    });
}
Messages.prototype.postResponse = function(){
    console.log('Post Response');
}
var messages = new Messages();
```

In the marked line ("ERROR HERE"), it's not recognizing the `Messages.postResponse()` function when I call it as `this.postResponse()`. I've also tried `self.postResponse()` without any success.

I'm sure it's a problem of scope; I'm just not sure how to refer to the actual object. Do I need to set `var me = this` and use that, or something?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why does your constructor set `this.postResponseButton` and then you read `self.postResponseButton`?

Comment: I realize now that I was using `self` because `this` wasn't working. I realize `this` wasn't working because `this` was the html document being passed through from the `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have said, the problem is that the context of the `click` event handler is not the same as the function in which it appears. Either [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (ES5, won't work in old browsers) the function to `this`:

```
Messages.prototype.setEvents = function(){
    $(self.postResponseButton).click(function(){
        this.postResponse();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Or save a reference to `this` and use that instead:

```
Messages.prototype.setEvents = function(){
    var that = this;
    $(self.postResponseButton).click(function(){
        that.postResponse();
    });
}
```

A third alternative would be to use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), which is effectively an alias for `Function.prototype.bind` including  a fallback for old browsers:

```
Messages.prototype.setEvents = function(){
    $(self.postResponseButton).click($.proxy(function(){
        this.postResponse();
    }, this));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough reply! I've tried each example but I keep receiving this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'postResponse'`. It seems like `this` is returning the document instead of the instance. Do you know why this is happening? Thanks again.

Comment: Ah! I see now. I repeated the same error in my `$(document).ready()` function. So by using bind (or your other examples) in both the `document.ready()` and `postResponse()` lines, the reference is being properly saved. Thanks a ton!